# Command to CD and start VIM with plugin

Tags: macos, bash, vim, terminal

I'm trying to improve my "switching projects" workflow.

Right now it works like this (I'm on OS X 10.6.7)

Open terminal.

I have this alias:

```
alias work='cd /Volumes/blah/Projects/'
```

So i type: "work" -> "cd ProjectName"

Then i Open VIM.

Inside i VIM, i always open :NERDTree plugin.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in one command like:

> workon ProjectName

(similar to what virtualenv has for python, where you use a "hook" to cd into a specified directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `~/.vimrc` add

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

This will automatically execute the vim command (starting the NERDTree plugin). Here's a short script that will achieve what you're after.

```
$ cat workon
#!/bin/bash

cd /Volumes/blah/Projects/$1
vim
```

Comment: I ended up running this in the script: vim --cmd "autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree". Thanks for the help

Comment: This can be written as a function (defined in .bashrc) instead of a separate script file: `workon() { cd /Volumes/blah/Project/"$1" && vim --cmd "..."; }`

Comment: @Daniel, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for posting!